# How to get x & y of a bitmap, the position of bitmap in the screen

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, path, android-drawable

I have a bitmap image that moves along a path, all I want is to be able to retrieve the x and y of the bitmap while it moving along the path.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

I think you mean ImageView instead of Bitmap. You set the image of an ImageView using a Bitmap and a Bitmap isn't a view.

Try using

```
int[] loc = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationOnScreen(loc)
```

or

```
int[] loc = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationInWindow(loc)
```

Comment: oh, sorry, you need to use them on a view, try `imageView.getLocationOnScreen(loc)`